# PowerShell is missing the terminator: "

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have the following script code

```
#[string]$password = $( Read-Host "Input password, please" )
param (
    [string]$ReleaseFile = $(throw "-ReleaseFile is required"),
    [string]$Destination = $(throw "-Destination is required")
)
 
function unzipRelease($src, $dst)
{
    $shell = new-object -com shell.application
    $zip = $shell.NameSpace($src)
    foreach($item in $zip.items())
    {
        $shell.Namespace($dst).copyhere($item)
    }
}

#  .\deployrelease.ps1 -ReleaseFile ".\deploy.zip" -Destination "."

unzipRelease –Src '$ReleaseFile' -Dst '$Destination'
```

I run the script with:  .\deployrelease.ps1 -ReleaseFile ".\deploy.zip" -Destination "."

But I keep getting this:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Tools> .\deployrelease.ps1 -ReleaseFile ".\deploy.zip" -Destination
The string starting:
At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Tools\deployrelease.ps1:19 char:16
+ unzipRelease â? <<<< "Src '$ReleaseFile' -Dst '$Destination'
is missing the terminator: ".
At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Tools\deployrelease.ps1:19 char:55
+ unzipRelease â?"Src '$ReleaseFile' -Dst '$Destination' <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (Src `'$ReleaseF...'$Destination`':String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

I couldn't find the fix as I do not see any problem.

Any help?

Comment: What editor are you using?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Look closely at the two dashes in

```
unzipRelease –Src '$ReleaseFile' -Dst '$Destination'
```

This first one is not a normal dash but an en-dash (`&ndash;` in HTML). Replace that with the dash found before `Dst`.

Answer (score 16):

In my specific case of the same issue, it was caused by not having the Powershell script saved with an encoding of Windows-1252 or UFT-8 WITH BOM.

Comment: Same issue here. I had some unicode characters in the script file, which was saved with an encoding of UTF-8 without BOM. Adding the BOM solved the issue.

Answer (score 7):

This can also occur when the path ends in a '' followed by the closing quotation mark.
e.g. The following line is passed as one of the arguments and this is not right:

> "c:\users\abc\"

instead pass that argument as shown below so that the last backslash is escaped instead of escaping the quotation mark.

> "c:\users\abc\\"

Answer (score 3):

In your script, why are you using single quotes around the variables? These will not be expanded. Use double quotes for variable expansion or just the variable names themselves.

```
unzipRelease –Src '$ReleaseFile' -Dst '$Destination'
```

to

```
unzipRelease –Src "$ReleaseFile" -Dst "$Destination"
```

Answer (score 2):

This error will also occur if you call `.ps1` file from a `.bat` file and file path has spaces.

The fix is to make sure there are no spaces in the path of `.ps1` file.

Answer (score 2):

if you're using RHEL, try replacing " with ' - this fixed the error for me

cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can spot the error when using `@` prefix/suffix with multiline string while you actually have the ending suffix `"@`.

My script looked like that:

```
Add-Type @"
    public class SomeClass {
        ...
    }"@
```

and I still got the: *The string is missing the terminator: "@*.

Message was misleading because all I needed to do was to put `"@` into **new line without any leading space**:

```
Add-Type @"
    public class SomeClass {
        ...
    }
"@
```

Answer (score 0):

my folder contained ' symbol. After I removed it, the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes mostly when you dont put the power shell variable under double quotes "variable_name"