# Unable to execute some commands in ps1 file from powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a windows service running on one of the Azure VMs.
So whenever a deployment has to be done, we copy the binaries manually. So now, I'm writing a script to do that.
Besically the binaries are in the form of a zip folder in `MachineA`. That zip folder is copied to `MachineB` (where windows service is running).After copying, the files are extracted and then zip folder is deleted. Then after the service is started.

To do this I have the below script.

```
#get session details
$UserName = "$IPAddress\$adminUsername"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $adminPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, $Password)
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $IPAddress -Credential $psCred

#stop the service
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {Stop-Service -Name "ServiceName" -Force} 

#delete existing binaries in destination machine
$tempDestPath = $destinationPath  + "\*"
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {param($tempDestPath)Remove-Item $tempDestPath -Recurse} -ArgumentList $tempDestPath

#copy binaries zip folder in destination machine
Copy-Item -Path $sourcePath -Destination $destinationPath -ToSession $s -Recurse

#extract zipfolder in destination machine
$zipFilePath = $destinationPath + "\" + $fileName
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {param($zipFilePath,$destinationPath) Expand-Archive $zipFilePath -DestinationPath $destinationPath}-ArgumentList $zipFilePath,$destinationPath

#delete zipfolder in destination machine after extraction
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {param($zipFilePath)Remove-Item –path $zipFilePath}-ArgumentList $zipFilePath

#start the service
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {Start-Service -Name "ServiceName"}
```

This is working fine when I open Windows powershell in `MachineA` and execute these commands one by one.
But when I put the exact same commands in a ps1 file and execute that file, I'm getting the below error:

```
At C:\ScriptTest\test.ps1:13 char:95
+ ...  -ScriptBlock {Start-Service -Name "ServiceName"}
+                                                                        ~~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
At C:\ScriptTest\test.ps1:11 char:42
+     Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {param($zipFilePath)Remov ...
+                                             ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

Where am I missing this terminator. I'm not able to figure out. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: the script is missing the PSSession $s. is the script provided all content of your `.ps1`-file? if so: add `New-PSSession` at the beginning; if not: please provide all content from the `ps1`-file

Comment: @GuentherSchmitz, all the variables , including $s has values in it. I just didn't mention those details in the question. I will add it anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out a - in one of the commands is wrong.
I have replaced this line

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {param($zipFilePath)Remove-Item –path $zipFilePath}-ArgumentList $zipFilePath
```

with this line

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {param($zipFilePath)Remove-Item -path $zipFilePath}-ArgumentList $zipFilePath
```

The hyphen in from of the path is slightly different.I was able to figure out from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20706950/8930751) answer

Comment: I'm unable to do it now.I need to wait for 2 days to do that.