# Powershell script to get output through Sql query in table format attached in email?

Tags: sql, powershell

**The below script is resulting in the error below when attempt to send mail is made.**

New-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '='.
At line:22 char:18
+ ... onnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection    $SqlCon ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Login failed for user ''."
At line:29 char:1
+ $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:44 char:17
+     -BodyAsHtml $html_table `
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

```bsh
$Servers = (Import-Csv -Path "D:\Scripts\input.csv").ComputerName    
$SQLDBName = "ReportServer"    
$SQLQuery = @"
    SELECT Distinct
        RL.RoleName,
        USR.UserName
    FROM  
        Catalog C
        INNER JOIN Policies PL 
                ON C.PolicyID = PL.PolicyID
        INNER JOIN PolicyUserRole PUR
                ON PUR.PolicyID = PL.PolicyID
        INNER JOIN Users USR
                ON PUR.UserID = USR.UserID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Roles RL
                ON RL.RoleID = PUR.RoleID    
        WHERE RoleName = 'Content Manager' 
        ORDER BY USR.UserName
"@

# This code connects to the SQL server and retrieves the data    
$SQLConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $Servers; Database = $SQLDBName;"    
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand    
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery    
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection    
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter    
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd    
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet    
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)    
$SqlConnection.Close()               

# This code outputs the retrieved data
$html = $DataSet.Tables[0] | ConvertTo-Html -fragment    
$results = $DataSet.Tables | format-table -autosize | out-string    
$mail_body = $results

# Send the email    
$html_table = $dt | sort-object "Status" | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment  

Send-MailMessage `
    -From "Reporting.Services@accenture.com" `
    -To 'aditi.m.singh@accenture.com' `
    -Subject 'Sending the Attachment' `
    -BodyAsHtml $html_table `
    -SmtpServer 'AMRINT.SMTP.ACCENTURE.COM'
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding more formatting to your code. (The block beginning with ```$Servers = ...```)

Comment: So the part that's commented out is resulting in the error?

Comment: @derekbaker783 the email part in bottom is saying as "The string is without terminator"

Comment: @derekbaker783 Under $Servers i am passing the input csv file with the database server name and under $sqldbname i am passing the db name and inside $SQLQuery i am passing the sql query .

Comment: @derekbaker783 After running the above formatted script this error is coming

Comment: you can edit your question to resolve any issues caused by the edit. It was edited because the original format was very hard to read.

Comment: @derekbaker783 the edits are fine it is throwing error at line 22,29 and 44

Comment: See if [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/6tgo82/getting_error_the_string_is_missing_the_terminator/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706869/powershell-is-missing-the-terminator) helps.

Comment: @derekbaker783 How to compare the  input csv file with the output from sql query  and if the values are not matching then trigger a mail in the below script. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. One issue you had is that the variable `$dt` was never initialized in your script.

```bsh
param(
    $emailFrom = 'Reporting.Services@accenture.com',
    $emailTo = 'aditi.m.singh@accenture.com',
    $emailSubject = 'Sending the Attachment',
    $smtp = 'AMRINT.SMTP.ACCENTURE.COM',
    $Server = "$Env:ComputerName\MSSQLSERVER01",
    $SQLDBName = 'Master',
    $SQLQuery = @"
        SELECT Distinct
            RL.RoleName,
            USR.UserName
        FROM  
            Catalog C
            INNER JOIN Policies PL 
                    ON C.PolicyID = PL.PolicyID
            INNER JOIN PolicyUserRole PUR
                    ON PUR.PolicyID = PL.PolicyID
            INNER JOIN Users USR
                    ON PUR.UserID = USR.UserID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Roles RL
                    ON RL.RoleID = PUR.RoleID    
            WHERE RoleName = 'Content Manager' 
            ORDER BY USR.UserName    
"@
)

# This code connects to the SQL server and retrieves the data    
$SQLConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection    
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $Server; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security=true;"    
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand    
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery    
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection    
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter    
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd    
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet    
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)    
$SqlConnection.Close()               

$data = $DataSet.Tables[0]
$html = $data `
    | Select-Object -Property RoleName, UserName `
        | ConvertTo-Html -fragment `
            | Out-String

Send-MailMessage `
    -From $emailFrom `
    -To $emailTo `
    -Subject $emailSubject `
    -BodyAsHtml $html `
    -SmtpServer $smtp
```

Comment: One minor thing with this answer is that the $SQLDBName should be = 'ReportServer' for the given SQL Query instead of Master.